# Running mnist_softmax.py on Tensorflow Installed with Docker

Tags: python, linux, docker, tensorflow

I installed Tensorflow on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS following the tutorial given here (with GPU support): [Docker Installation for Tensorflow](http://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_steup.html#docker-installation)

Managed to run docker with this command:

```
nvidia-docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -v /home/myusername/notebooks:/notebooks gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu 

docker exec -it [my_DOCKER_ID] bash
```

Once I managed to get into the docker bash successfully, I found that there is tensorflow directory here:

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/models/image/mnist/
```

I proceeded to try the example code and successfully reached Test error of 0.8%:

```
python convolutional.py
```

Next, following https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html tutorial page, I would like to try mnist_softmax.py. So I cloned tensorflow's package to /notebooks:

```
cd /notebooks
git clone https://githubcom/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
```

However, I found problem when running the code:

```
cd tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/

python mnist_softmax.py --data_dir /notebooks/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist
```

> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> >
> > ```
> > File "mnist_softmax.py", line 78, in <module>
> >
> >   tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
> >
> > TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'argv'
> > ```

At this point I'm pretty clueless whether the error was caused by bad installation or it's because there are steps that I havent done. My questions:

1. Is my installation complete? I assumed I had a clean installation knowing that I can run docker and get into the docker bash. Plus, I managed to run convolution.py
2. If I understand Docker correctly, I do not need to clone and build tensorflow package at all?

Comment: Are you able to run any other example?

Comment: I do have the same problem. Please, let me know if you fix it.

Comment: @drpng I tried convolutional.py and was successful. I then cloned tensorflow github repo and tried running mnist_softmax.py without success

Comment: So I tried building from source at the current HEAD, and it seems to work. Please try again with a newer version.

Comment: @drpng so if i understand correctly, you are installing it from source instead of docker installation? I wish to use docker installation to isolate the environment

Comment: No, it should work either way. You can of course also build tensorflow within docker. But you should try a later version, maybe there was some transient error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and it was caused by running tutorial code from a later version (eg v0.12) against an older version of tensorflow which was in my docker container (v0.11 in my case).
The same problem is discussed here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5643

The app.run() method didn't have the argv parameter until v0.12.